# ASP.NET Forms Authentication and a "No Authentication" subfolder

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, webforms, forms-authentication

Is it possible to disable all authentication in a subfolder of a web site that is Forms Authenticated? How do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, place a web.config file on the subfolder with this content:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Actually I noticed then I couldn't get to some connection strings in the web.config one level below this new one. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: It could have been cause by the <connectionStrings/> tag in the original post

Comment: Although the solution might seem obvious and simple, this helped me figure out a hair-puller. Thanks!

Comment: Is this different than adding a <location> tag with the same content inside the root web.config?

Answer (score 4):

yes you can, you can use [location tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) in the web.config to configure folder level security.

Comment: I would probably use this method if I had many locations to specify differently and I wanted to manage them from a central file. good answer. +1