# Using Basic Authentication and Forms authentication on same site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis-7

Can anyone tell me, if it is possible to use both basic and forms authentication on my site without the 2 interfering with each other?

I have a new site that I want only certain people to see for approval purposes.

The site has a members area that uses Forms authentication and now when anyone enters the site after passing basic authentication they are being directed to the forms authentication page, even though they should be viewing a page that isn't protected by forms authentication.

I need a situation whereby anyone who clears basic authentication can then view the whole site excluding the members area of the site where they will need to log in via forms authentication.

Comment: How is your authentication set up right now?

Comment: Please post some details (code or pseudo-code) about how your authentication/authorization is configured now. This sounds more like an *authorization* problem than an authentication problem if you are being redirected to the wrong place. Are you using `AuthorizeAttribute`? Are you using `AllowAnonymousAttribute`? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated the question. The `[Authorize]` attribute is being used and working as intended with Forms Authentication. However, the whole site needs to be protected with Basic Authentication. I.e. When a user tries to access the site, they are prompted with a browser login dialog. After clearing this, the user should to be able to view the whole site, excluding methods/controllers with `[Authorize]` attributes (where Forms Authentication is required for access to these parts of the site)

Comment: I'm confused why this wasn't asked as a new question. Isn't basic and Windows authentication two different things in IIS?

Comment: Possibly Related: [Using the browser’s native login prompt](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/). This article shows how you can replace your own login form with basic authentication. Since it uses forms authentication, [Authorize] attribute works as it normally would. If you want to control access to different areas of the site - well, that is what roles are for. Controlling access is an *authorization* problem, not an *authentication* problem.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just haven't configured forms authentication for just the particular members area, but have it configured for everything.

Look at [the authorization element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t) and [the location element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7) (if you want to control the settings in the main Web.config, instead of creating a Web.config for the member's area).

See also [ASP.NET Forms Authentication and a "No Authentication" subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425514/asp-net-forms-authentication-and-a-no-authentication-subfolder) (except you want the reverse).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to write your own basic authentication filter attribute and protect the action that just require basic authentication with the custom attribute . The controller action which requires forms authentication should be protected with the normal [Authorize] attribute. Please refer the following example :-

http://www.ryadel.com/en/http-basic-authentication-asp-net-mvc-using-custom-actionfilter/

I had a similar issue in the past but was more along the lines of providing basic authentication for REST calls and form authentication when someone access the mvc site. We ended up creating our own authentication filter