# ColdFusion with IIS Forms Based Authentication

Tags: iis, coldfusion, forms-authentication

I'm trying to setup [Forms Based Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx) in IIS 7.5 with ColdFusion 10. It's somewhat working but not prompting for ColdFusion pages. Yes, I did enable the [Integrated Pipeline](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline#htmlrewrite_content_rewrite) to force auth on all files. Then, I [disabled auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425514/asp-net-forms-authentication-and-a-no-authentication-subfolder) on the two ColdFusion Virtual Directories. Not doing so caused a redirect to /jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll instead of the real/calling page.

So the interesting thing is that ColdFusion files (.cfm .cfc) seem to get past the authentication because they are processed by the un-authenticated Virtual Directories.?. (even though the requested page is still the called page..)

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a workaround but I'm not sure it is the right/best solution. Basically disable Anonymous Authentication EXCEPT for the ColdFusion Virtual Directories and the folder that contains the login page. Open to any other ideas anyone might have.

Now, to get Forms Based Authentication using ColdFusion with .NET objects... :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the FormAuthentication iis module was not being called for `isapi_redirect.dll(jakarta pages)` probably because of the precondition `preCondition="managedHandler"` that's default on FormAuthentication module.
Adding

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >;
```

in `web.config` allowed things to work as intended.

Enabling Trace Logging for Failed Requests were indispensable in figuring this out.  This was with win2016/cf2016/iis10.